# maven scope for woven artifacts

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, aspectj

I have a project `foo-instrumented` that depends on `foo`.

This project actually instruments `foo` with additional code, and replaces it. That is, `foo` is a compile-time dependency of `foo-instrumented` but it is definitely not a runtime dependency (`foo-instrumented` *replaces* `foo`), and it should not be propagated to children (that is, projects depending on `foo-instrumented` should *not* end up depending on `foo`).

Is there an appropriate maven scope for that kind of dependency, or another solution?

**Edit**: I am not being clear enough with my request: although `foo` should not end up in the children project dependencies, `foo`'s dependencies should (e.g. if `foo` depends on `log4j`, then a project that depends on `foo-instrumented` should have `log4j` as part of its dependencies), which seems to rule out the `provided` scope.

Thanks!

**Edit**: Okay, I need to have a little rant here: DID ANY REAL, ACTUAL HUMAN BEING ACTUALLY UNDERSTAND THE MAVEN DOCS? I had a look at a few [pages](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) and guess what: no explanations, no illustrations, JUST TONS OF XML VOMIT. XML VOMIT IS NOT DOCUMENTATION, PEOPLE!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [import](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) scope.  In your foo-instrumented project:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    <dependency>
<dependencies>
```

This will pull the dependencies of foo into foo-instrumented without also including foo.

Comment: This is the most promising answer yet, but I did not manage to have it working (I still need to pull the dependency at compile/weaving time)

Comment: @Rom1 - You'll also need to pull foo as a compile-time dependency (scope-> compile; no type element).  If that still doesn't work can you post your pom.xml for foo-instrumented?

Comment: I am a bit reluctant to post my pom file, but here is a warning I get after declaring the import dependency:

[WARNING] build config error: skipping missing, empty or corrupt inpath entry: /home/me/.m2/repository/bar/foo/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

Comment: @Rom1 - it sounds like something is wrong with that pom file in your local repo.  What happens when you delete it and do a `mvn install` in the foo project?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot exclude a dependency, but still include it's dependencies.
However, you can define an exclusion for your non-instrumented dependency and add the dependencies over to your other module (again). When you define the dependency to `foo-instrumented`, do:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo-instrumented</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bar</groupId>
                <!-- Exclude the non-instrumented dependency: -->
                <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    <dependency>

   <!-- Add the dependencies you need for foo to work here -->
<dependencies>
```

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, but it is not very elegant.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a better way.